# How to check whether my cron job for backup using tar was succesfull

Tags: cron, backup, tar

I have a cron job to tar backup websites and databases and upload the backup to a NAS.

Instead of checking the tar files on the NAS. Is there any way to check if the tar backup process completed successfully?

Comment: Most cron daemons I have used in linux will email you if the command returns non-zero by default.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at how you word your question, I am under the impression that your knowledge of linux is not very extensive. If this is the case:

1. In the script, responsible for running the backup process, put these lines right after the line containing `tar -cvf...` command

   ```
   result=${?}
   if [ ${result} -ne 0 ]
   then
      echo "tar backup failed" | mailx -s "backup results" me@mycompany.com
   else 
      echo "tar backup completed successfully" | mailx -s "backup results" me@mycompany.com
   fi
   ```

   -or-

   if you have a tar command in your crontab, make sure you have a valid email address in /etc/passwd file for the user, running the tar backup (most likely `root`), such that, when this cron job fails, system will send an email to the address specified.
2. at this point, make sure your server is capable of sending emails to your company mail servers. If you are not sure how it is done, look for help on sendmail administration.